# bash script to find the product of two numbers in succession to each other up to a max number

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, git-bash

hey guys im trying to write a script to find the product of two number in successionn to each other like `1*2 2*3 3*4` etc... up to a max number but I keep getting this error on line 14

```
./test.sh: line 14: ((: 2=1: attempted assignment to non-variable (error token is "=1")
```

and not sure what I'm doing wrong very new to bash any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash
#A script to find the products of two nonnegative numbers in succesion to each other up to a maximum 
number>
a=1
b=2
prod=$(($a*$b))
count=1
echo "Input The max number to find product of numbers in succesion with each other up to."
read maxnum
echo "Ok all the products of numbers in succesion to each other from 1 to" $maxnum  "are as follows."
for (( $b=1; $b<=$maxnum; $bb++ ))
do
        for (( $a=1; $a<$b; $a++ ))
        do
                for (( $count=1; $count<=$maxnum; ++$count ))
                do
                        echo $count". "$prod
                done
        done
done
echo "You have now reached the end of your range of products with integers in succession to each 
other"
```

Comment: Can you post an example of your input and the output expected

Comment: Where is the script will "prod" get modified after the initial setup ?

Comment: Please paste your script first at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: so basically i am trying to write a script that will allow a user to input a maximum number for a range of number like 10 then the program will multiply sets of two numbers in succession to each other up to that given range like this
Please enter a maximum number for range 
10
Ok all the products of numbers in succesion to each other from 1 to" $maxnum  are as follows.
1. 2
2. 6
3. 12
4. 20
5. 30
6. 42
7. 56
8. 72
9. 90

Comment: Please update the question to include the desired output

Comment: I rolled back your latest edit (still available from the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/99d54e8b-1e3e-4429-ac6f-7fa562a7692e/view-source)); accept the answer you got (or post a answer of your own and accept that) and post a new question about your new problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (($b=1;...
#     ~
#     ^
```

Don't use the dollar sign in assignments.

BTW, you can omit all the dollar signs in arithmetic expressions.

```
for ((b=1; b<=maxnum; b++ ))
```

Are you sure the `bb` shouldn't be just `b`?

Comment: yes it was supposed to be just b ive since changed that and the program runs now after using shellcheck.net but its not running as it should the output isnt quite right I will update the post to reflect this

Comment: No, please, ask a new question. Changing it makes existing comments and answers useless.

Comment: oh sorry I did not know that